# avrdude - how to only write to device?

Tags: avr, atmel, avrdude

I've been using the `avrdude` for quite some time to burn my `atmega` mcu's. The read / write operations are fast if the code is small in size but it gets a lot slower as the code base grows.

I've noticed that `avrdude` not only writes from the `mcu` but also reads the on-chip data. I wasn't able to find anything regarding the issue in `man avrdude`.

Is it even possible to only write using `avrdude`?

Comment: Option `-V` (capital V, not lowercase v) disables verify. (default is to verify after write.)

Comment: @MarkU Post it as an answer I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [AVRDUDE documentation, 2.1 Option Descriptions](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html), 
the command-line option "-V" disables automatic verify check when uploading data.

```
-V
Disable automatic verify check when uploading data.
```

Note that this is a capital V not lowercase v, which enables verbose output.

```
-v
Enable verbose output. More -v options increase verbosity level.
```

Normally it's correct for avrdude to verify after writing, to ensure that the operation completed successfully. The only reason to disable the verification check is to save firmware loading time, on a setup that you have already deemed reliable.